# Hair dynamics does not affect all grass stands, some are frozen

Tags: particles

I'm using hair dynamics to simulate grass blowing in the wind. When hair dynamics is activated, some hairs do not move at all. About 1-2% stand still. I don't understand and cannot find a explanation for this after searching the net. Hope someone here can advise?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by deleting the emitter and particle system and re-creating it. When I made my emitter more complex (not a flat plane) and added more hairs it all worked fine.

Comment: There is stilll the possibilty that you had a supperposition of two particle system, but it look more like a bug. It's always a good think to start again from scratch when you have unexpected result, but it would have been interresting to see if a relaunch of blender could have been enough.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem, it seems to happen when the strand-points are to irregularly apart.
I kinda found a solution by going into particle edit mode, selecting the problematic strands and using the function: Rekey
you need to test how many numbers of keys you need. for me, some strands needed 14 other 10...
if there are still some left or you haven't much strands in total, search where the big gapses are and subdivide them.
not the best solution but the only one i know without deleting your whole work...